# How to get the output as mentioned in description C Language

Tags: c, math

**EDITED:**

I am getting 3 different numbers from console using scanf function. (Restriction: Only Integers may ne negative , positive). I have to arrange these numbers in such order such that it will show the desending order with there proper operator relation like:

```
Input:
    Enter 1st Num: 6
    Enter 2nd Num: 3
    Enter 3rd Num: 4

Expected Output: 6 > 3 > 2
```

#### #

```
Input:
    Enter 1st Num: 3
    Enter 2nd Num: 2
    Enter 3rd Num: 6

Expected Output: 6 > 3 > 2
```

#

```
Input:
    Enter 1st Num: 6
    Enter 2nd Num: 6
    Enter 3rd Num: 4

Expected Output: 6 = 6 > 4
```

#### #

```
Input:
    Enter 1st Num: 6
    Enter 2nd Num: 3
    Enter 3rd Num: 3

Expected Output: 6 > 3 = 3
```

#### #

```
Input:
    Enter 1st Num: 6
    Enter 2nd Num: 6
    Enter 3rd Num: 6

Expected Output: 6 = 6 = 6
```

### #

NOTE: I have done the same kind of program for 2 numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter 1st Num:");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter 2nd Num:");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    if (a>b)
    {
        printf("%d > %d",a,b);
    }
    else 
    {
        if (b > a){
            printf("%d > %d",b,a);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d = %d", a,b); 
        }
}
return 0;
```

}

Output for the following code is:

```
Input:
    Enter 1st Num: 4
    Enter 2nd Num: 5

Output: 5 > 4
```

#### #

```
Input:
    Enter 1st Num: 5
    Enter 2nd Num: 4

Output: 5 > 4
```

#### #

```
Input:
    Enter 1st Num: 4
    Enter 2nd Num: 4

Output: 4 = 4
```

Comment: Please show what you have done to try and solve the problem.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: We are happy to help you from the part your struck up with... Share your progress /code

Comment: @DavidChelliah: I have updated the question.

Comment: @hobenkr: Hopefully now you can get what is my exact requirement.! :)

Comment: @impinball: I have tried lots of scenarios and I can do the same program but the logic which I am using is quite big and I am sure there must be short way to solve the same problem. Anyway thanks foe your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1):

A method to print the numbers:

```
void sort(int a, int b, int c)
{
   int top, mid, bot;
   if (a > b)
   {
      if (c > a)
      {
         top = c;
         mid = a;
         bot = b;
      }
      else
      {
         top = a;
         if (c > b)
         {
            mid = c;
            bot = b;
         }
         else
         {
            mid = b;
            bot = c;   
         }
      }
   }
   else
   {
      if (c > b)
      {
         top = c;
         mid = b;
         bot = a;
      }
      else
      {
         top = b;
         if (c > a)
         {
            mid = c;
            bot = a;
         }
         else
         {
            mid = a;
            bot = c;   
         }
      }
   }

   printf("%i %c %i %c %i \n", 
          top, (top == mid) ? '=' : '>',
          mid, (mid == bot) ? '=' : '>', 
          bot);
}
```